# get heading/facing direction using only satelite latitude/longitude

Tags: android, location, maps, nmea

I get my location from an NMEA reader and this does not return bearing which is an issue. I want to always show the direction the user of the app is facing, just like how google maps location layer has a small arrow indicating direction user is facing.
I have tried using true North as a fixed destination point and thus calculating bearing from my location to True North. But this does not work as i expected.(When i turn, the marker does not rotate with that bearing), and i tried using the electromagnetic sensor but it is not available in my techno phone.
So, with only a latitude and Longitude, is there a way i can figure out where the user is facing? And probably draw an arrow in that direction? (The lat/lng keep coming in, in real time from my custom location provider in nmea format)

**note: I don't have a set/absolute destination point so bearingTo might not be helpful. I just get the coordinates, and want to know where I'm facing at any one point**

Answer (score 0):

> I get my location from an NMEA reader and this does not return bearing which is an issue.

> When i turn, the marker does not rotate with that bearing

Well, yes, you can't calculate your orientation without any data to do so with.  You need to be moving in a direction.  If there is no track heading in the `RMC` message, or other messages, then the only way is to calculate one yourself by using several points over time and figuring out a vector from there.  This requires that you are moving in a direction, and not simply rotating.